# C++ OpenSSL export private key

Tags: c++, cryptography, openssl, rsa, pem

I'm using SSL successfully so far, but have come up against a confusing roadblock. I generate an RSA keypair, and previously was using PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey(...) to export them. However the man pages claim that format is outdated (and indeed it looks different to the usual PEM format). Instead it recommends PEM_write_bio_PKCS8PrivateKey(...).

However PEM_write_bio_PKCS8PrivateKey accepts an EVP_PKEY object. How can I convert my RSA* keypair into an EVP_PKEY* structure for usage in that function?

```
EVP_PKEY* evpkey = EVP_PKEY_new();
if (!EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(evpkey, keypair))
    throw ReadError();
int ret = PEM_write_bio_PKCS8PrivateKey(bio, evpkey, EVP_aes_256_cbc(),
                                        pass_char_str, pass_len, NULL, NULL);
```

ret is always 0. Using the older PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey works for me. I'm looking to export my keys so they look like:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICXQIBAAKBgQCvdbGZes3N/v3EqbbwYHW4rr4Wgav9eD36kVD7Hn5LIKwhfAqd
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of 'pass_len'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this [forum posting here](http://www.bitcoin.org/smf/index.php?topic=4966.0) (snippet below):

```
void AccessCard::PrivateKey(string& pem, const string& passphrase) const
{
    CheckKey();
    BioBox bio;
    bio.NewBuffer();

    EvpBox evp(keypair);
    int ret = PEM_write_bio_PKCS8PrivateKey(bio.Bio(), evp.Key(),
                                            EVP_aes_256_cbc(),
                                            LoseStringConst(passphrase),
                                            passphrase.size(), NULL, NULL);
    if (!ret)
        throw ReadError();
    const BioBox::Buffer& buf = bio.ReadAll();
    pem = string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buf.buf), buf.size);
}
```

**Full Source:**

```
#include <string>
#include <exception>
using std::string;

//typedef struct RSA;
#include <openssl/rsa.h>

class ReadError : public std::exception
{
public:
    virtual const char* what() const throw();
};

class NoKeypairLoaded : public std::exception
{
public:
    virtual const char* what() const throw();
};

class AccessCard
{
public:
    AccessCard();
    ~AccessCard();
    void Generate();
    void Load(const string& pem, const string& pass);
    void PublicKey(string& pem) const;
    void PrivateKey(string& pem, const string& passphrase) const;

private:
    void CheckKey() const;

    RSA* keypair;
};

class BioBox
{
public:
    struct Buffer
    {
        void* buf;
        int size;
    };

    BioBox();
    ~BioBox();
    void ConstructSink(const string& str);
    void NewBuffer();
    BIO* Bio() const;
    Buffer ReadAll();
private:
    BIO* bio;
    Buffer buf;
};

class EvpBox
{
public:
    EvpBox(RSA* keyp);
    ~EvpBox();
    EVP_PKEY* Key();
private:
    EVP_PKEY* evpkey;
};

//--------------------
#include <openssl/pem.h>

const char* ReadError::what() const throw()
{
    return "Problem reading BIO.";
}
const char* NoKeypairLoaded::what() const throw()
{
    return "No keypair loaded.";
}

AccessCard::AccessCard()
  : keypair(NULL)
{
    if (EVP_get_cipherbyname("aes-256-cbc") == NULL)
        OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
}
AccessCard::~AccessCard()
{
    RSA_free(keypair);
}
void AccessCard::CheckKey() const
{
    if (!keypair)
        throw NoKeypairLoaded();
}

void AccessCard::Generate()
{
    RSA_free(keypair);
    keypair = RSA_generate_key(2048, RSA_F4, NULL, NULL);
    CheckKey();
}

static char *LoseStringConst(const string& str)
{
    return const_cast<char*>(str.c_str());
}
static void* StringAsVoid(const string& str)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<void*>(LoseStringConst(str));
}

BioBox::BioBox()
 : bio(NULL)
{
    buf.buf = NULL;
    buf.size = 0;
}
BioBox::~BioBox()
{
    BIO_free(bio);
    free(buf.buf);
}
void BioBox::ConstructSink(const string& str)
{
    BIO_free(bio);
    bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(StringAsVoid(str), -1);
    if (!bio)
        throw ReadError();
}
void BioBox::NewBuffer()
{
    BIO_free(bio);
    bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    if (!bio)
        throw ReadError();
}
BIO* BioBox::Bio() const
{
    return bio;
}
BioBox::Buffer BioBox::ReadAll()
{
    buf.size = BIO_ctrl_pending(bio);
    buf.buf = malloc(buf.size);
    if (BIO_read(bio, buf.buf, buf.size) < 0) {
        //if (ERR_peek_error()) {
        //    ERR_reason_error_string(ERR_get_error());
        //    return NULL;
        //}
        throw ReadError();
    }
    return buf;
}

EvpBox::EvpBox(RSA* keyp)
{
    evpkey = EVP_PKEY_new();
    if (!EVP_PKEY_set1_RSA(evpkey, keyp)) {
        throw ReadError();
    }
}
EvpBox::~EvpBox()
{
    EVP_PKEY_free(evpkey);
}
EVP_PKEY* EvpBox::Key()
{
    return evpkey;
}

static int pass_cb(char* buf, int size, int rwflag, void* u)
{
    const string pass = reinterpret_cast<char*>(u);
    int len = pass.size();
    // if too long, truncate
    if (len > size)
        len = size;
    pass.copy(buf, len);
    return len;
}
void AccessCard::Load(const string& pem, const string& pass)
{
    RSA_free(keypair);
    BioBox bio;
    bio.ConstructSink(pem);
    keypair = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(bio.Bio(), NULL, pass_cb,
                                         StringAsVoid(pass));
    CheckKey();                     
}
void AccessCard::PublicKey(string& pem) const
{
    CheckKey();
    BioBox bio;
    bio.NewBuffer();
    int ret = PEM_write_bio_RSA_PUBKEY(bio.Bio(), keypair);
    if (!ret)
        throw ReadError();
    const BioBox::Buffer& buf = bio.ReadAll();
    pem = string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buf.buf), buf.size);
}

void AccessCard::PrivateKey(string& pem, const string& passphrase) const
{
    CheckKey();
    BioBox bio;
    bio.NewBuffer();

    EvpBox evp(keypair);
    int ret = PEM_write_bio_PKCS8PrivateKey(bio.Bio(), evp.Key(),
                                            EVP_aes_256_cbc(),
                                            LoseStringConst(passphrase),
                                            passphrase.size(), NULL, NULL);
    if (!ret)
        throw ReadError();
    const BioBox::Buffer& buf = bio.ReadAll();
    pem = string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buf.buf), buf.size);
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
// this wont be in the final file... it's our unit test
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
using std::cout;

int main()
{
    AccessCard acc;                                                    
    // New key
    acc.Generate();
    string pem;
    // Get public key
    acc.PublicKey(pem);
    cout << pem << "\n";
    // Get private key
    acc.PrivateKey(pem, "hello");
    cout << pem << "\n";
    // Load a private key using pass 'hello'
    acc.Load(pem, "hello");
    acc.PublicKey(pem);
    cout << pem << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user561036: Glad I was able to give you some attention. Feel free to edit if you can make this answer better!